# Feature: maximum privacy

Tags: transloadit

Transloadit uses a temporary url for our files. I currently need to upload some important files to my rackspace cloud private container.. i have all setup but seems that, after uploading, users can read assembly result with js. Rackspace urls can be read but, because its a private container, rackspace url (and ssl_url) are inaccessible from user.

The problem is that, there is also a transloadit temporary url that contains that file.

Is there anyway to **disable** that temporary url so that we can guarantee to our users that their **files are not publicly accessible**? If not, can this flag be implemented so that we can use it on our template?

best
FA

Answer (score 0):

we use that temporary URL for machine-to-machine communication of files. I realize this is not ideal, and we could implement a flag that auto-deletes all temporary files of an assembly after its execution.

In the future we will also likely move to Amazon EFS which will remove the need for the temporary URLs entirely.

Kind regards,
Tim

Co-Founder Transloadit
@tim_kos

Comment: Right, but is there anyway to implement a flag that removes the returned temporary url ?

Comment: Yes, we'll implement this soon.